# Unable to connect to USB 3G Mobile Broadband

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, 3g, gsm

I am using Arch Linux, Trying to connect to internet using my D-Link mobilebroadband. ( using NetworkManager and ModemManager )

I configured it using GUI ( setting APN/Network -Vodafone etc.. )

But when trying to connect, it shows this :

```
$ nmcli device connect cdc-wdm0 
Error: Timeout 90 sec expired.
```

"/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Vodafone\ Vodafone\ Connect" file looks like this :

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Vodafone\ Vodafone\ Connect 

[connection]
id=Vodafone Vodafone Connect
uuid=6700a92d-d76c-4591-86c8-df2d8d3d30f1
type=gsm
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:severus:;

[gsm]
apn=www
number=*99#

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

the  "/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf" file is **empty**

output of `journalctl -r -S "2017-06-06" -u NetworkManager` ->https://ptpb.pw/xiud

output of `journalctl -r -S "2017-06-06" -u ModemManager` https://ptpb.pw/s7ER

**NOTE:** The same USB works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of output. Why can't you just copy the config from Ubuntu? And did Ubuntu set it up automatically for you?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I tried copying config from Ubuntu, but same problem persists. Yes Ubuntu set up most of the things automatically

Answer (score 0):

In the logfile you see that NM is constantly crashing and restarting. 
It's a bug, fixed upstream https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=30d06b2253b7277ed1153bcbbc81f9e1ca3e3474

Comment: are you sure ? because the description of that patch says "Fixes a crash with *Bluetooth* devices where the device is the BlueZ device and iface stays 0 while the IP interface is the actual BNEP link."

Comment: Pretty sure that the patch fixes your bug. The patch description may not be accurate and also apply to WWan.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to install that patch ? Please add it in your answer

Comment: You would rebuild upstream NM from source or rebuild your Arch package (with the patch applied). But in general, if you have to ask: don't do that (unless it's for a learning experience). Instead, open/follow a bug for your distribution and see/wait that your distribution fixes the package. An alternative might be to downgrade NM to an older version from your distribution, that doesn't have the problem.